# Android TextInputField Inflator Error in lower device

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am working on an android application. If i am running the application with above lolipop it is working fine. but if iam trying to run in jelly bean its getting `InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: hirerate.softweb.com.hirerate, PID: 1542
>                                                                                android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                    at hirerate.softweb.com.hirerate.Fragment.BuyerSignupFragment.onCreateView(BuyerSignupFragment.java:81)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2209)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16961)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2347)
>                                                                                   at android.view.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padd_10">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/texthead"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:drawableTint="@color/lavendar"
            android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_mail"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_mail"
            android:hint="@string/email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled = "true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/liggrey"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/asl_password_visibility"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padd_10">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/texthead"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:drawableTint="@color/lavendar"
            android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_key"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_key"
            android:hint="@string/password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#3A3A80</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3A3A80</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/secondary_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958972/inflateexception-with-textinputlayout-and-alertdialog

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569071/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-textinputlayout

Comment: I have tried with the above link.but still it shows the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566152/android-support-design-widget-textinputlayout-gives-inflateexception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046124/android-error-inflating-class-textinputlayout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578976/android-textinputfield-inflator-error

Comment: still it is not working

Comment: can u share your layout with question

Comment: i have edit my question with layout.

Comment: for test case try to remove `android:drawableTint="@color/lavendar"` from edittext

Comment: still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:drawableTint="@color/lavendar`" and  `android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_mail"` they require min api level 23 and 26 respectively

Comment: I have tried this. But still its getting the same error